# How to optimize reading character from input so the user does not need to specify the number of characters beforehand

Tags: c, optimization, char, user-input

**Current state of program**

I am making a program which reads the users input of chars until a new line and prints them out in reverse order.

The output i get is correct but i want to optimize the code.

In main i have written code that executes my Insert function n times (n represents the number of chars the user wants to input). So right now the user first need to input the amout of chars they want to input and then they can input the chars.

**How i actually want it**

I want to make it so that the user can just input the chars without having to first specify the number of chars they want to enter.

**My attempts**

Tried using a while loop but got wrong result:

Entered "asdf" as input

and got "fs" as output

```
int main(){
struct Node* head = NULL;
printf("Enter the chars you want to type: ");
while (getchar() != '\n') {
head = Insert(head,getchar());
}
Print(head);
}
```

Tried using a if statement but got wrong result:

Entered "asdf" as input

and got "s" as output

```
int main(){
struct Node* head = NULL;
printf("Enter the chars you want to type: ");
if (getchar() != '\n') {
head = Insert(head,getchar());
}
Print(head);
}
```

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct Node {
  char data;
  struct Node* linkToNext;
};



void Print(struct Node* head){
  while (head != NULL) {
    printf("%c", head -> data);
    head = head -> linkToNext;
  }
}



struct Node* Insert(struct Node* head, char input){
  struct Node* pointerToNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
  pointerToNode -> data = input;
  pointerToNode ->linkToNext = head;
  head = pointerToNode;
  return head;
}



int main(){
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  int i, n;
  printf("Enter the amout of chars you want to type: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    head = Insert(head,getchar());
  }
    Print(head);
}
```

**Example result of running code**

Enter the amout of chars you want to type: 4

asdf

fdsa

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem description. Please see [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the tip, I added more detail instead of writing didn't work. Do you mean `printf("%c", head -> data);` If so it prints out the char stored at the node the head is pointing at.

Comment: No, I meant multiple calls to `getchar`, but I realized that the example was more confusing than helpful due to the unspecified evaluation order of function arguments, so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Every call to `getchar()` reads and returns another character from the standard input.

Consider what happens with code like

```
while (getchar() != '\n') {
//     ^^^^^^^^^ #1

    head = Insert(head,getchar());
//                     ^^^^^^^^^ #2

}
```

and a user input of `asdf`.

The call labeled #1 reads and returns `'a'` (the first character of input), which is not `'\n'`, so the loop body is executed.

Then the call labeled #2 reads and returns `'s'` (the next character), which is added to the list.

Then we go back to the loop condition. `getchar()` #1 reads and returns `'d'`, which is still not `'\n'` ...

... and `getchar()` #2 reads and returns `'f'`, which is also added to the list.

Finally `getchar()` #1 reads a newline, which terminates the loop.

Because of the two calls to `getchar` in every iteration, only every second character was added to the list.

Your second attempt is similar, but `if` is not a loop, so only the second character *total* (`'s'` in `asdf`) was added to the list.

To fix this, you need to store the return value of `getchar` in a variable so you can compare it and add it to the list without reading more characters:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    head = Insert(head, c);
}
```

The additional check for `EOF` is to prevent your program from going into an infinite loop in case the input is not terminated by `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this using recursion.Just call the following function in your code.

```
void printRev(){
  char a;
  a = getchar();
  if(a == '\n'){
      return;
  }
  printRev();
  putchar(a);
}
```

here you don't need for specifying the size of the input. you just scan until you hit enter then print during return.

Comment: How does `putchar(a);` get executed? To me it looks like  `printRev();` makes it so you jump back to the top.

Comment: it is a recursive function, when calling a function, a copy of it is in the memory(stack). so, when calling printRev(); every time, there is a copy of the function into the stack with different values to variable a. the putchar(a) will be executed when the last called printRev() returned, which is when you hit enter the function will return from the if statement. are you got it?

Comment: I wouldn't do that at all. Each recursive call (on each character encountered) grows the stack. A few thousand characters entered  and you will provoke a stack-overflow. This solution imposes a limit on how many characters can be entered on std input and introduces a way to crash the program.